# How to make table numbering as table section_number alpha

Tags: tables, numbering, alphabet

I would like the numbering of tables in a section to be in the following format:

Table section_number alpha: table caption.

For examples, tables of section 4.3 should look like:

**Table 4.3 a**: Table one of section 4.3

**Table 4.3 b**: Table two of section 4.3

How can I do it?

Thanks!

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please help us to help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: Do you just want to be letters instead of numbers for your table?

Comment: Yes. Thanks for you answer Christian! It works!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Writing this in your preamble:

```
\usepackage[labelfont={bf, sf}]{caption}
\usepackage{chngcntr}
\counterwithin*{table}{section}
\renewcommand{\thetable}{\thesection~\alph{table}}
```

should produce table labels and counters as you describe (unsure you want the label in sans serif font!). Here is an example produced with that code in a standard class of documents:

[image]

Comment: Yes. Or rather no, it's not. Usually, it is reset per chapter (my example comes from a `report`document class.

Comment: The `chngcntr` package avoids the usage of `\makeatletter` and also offers a way to go back from the binding of a counter to another one.

Comment: @egreg: I saw that, but it seemed to default the table counter to arabic, and I don't know how to change it to alph.

Comment: `\counterwithin*{table}{section}` and `\renewcommand{\thetable}{...}` afterwards. The `*`-variant here is more efficient, because it doesn't do the default `\renewcommand` using `\arabic`.

Comment: @egreg: That's what I've just checked. Should have tried before… I modify my answer at once.